# Series expansion of $e^x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

I don't understand why a solution of

$$e^{rdt}(u+d)-ud-e^{2rdt}=\sigma^2dt$$

is

$$u=e^{\sigma \sqrt{dt}} \space \space \space \space\text{and}\space \space\space \space d=e^{-\sigma \sqrt{dt}}$$

My text says only that "*Neglecting the terms of order $dt^2$ and higher, a solution of the equation is $u=e^{\sigma \sqrt{dt}}$ and $d=e^{-\sigma \sqrt{dt}}$. Please note: we are using the series expansion $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...$*".

Could you show me the passages to arrive at $\sigma^2dt$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $u=e^{\sigma \sqrt{dt}}$ and $d=e^{-\sigma \sqrt{dt}}$ and using the series expansion we have $$ e^{rdt}(u+d)-ud-e^{2rdt}=e^{rdt}\big(e^{\sigma \sqrt{dt}}+e^{-\sigma \sqrt{dt}}\big)-1-e^{2rdt}$$
$$=(1+rdt+...)(1+\sigma \sqrt{dt}+\sigma^2\frac{dt}{2}+...+1-\sigma \sqrt{dt}+\sigma^2\frac{dt}{2}+...)-1-(1+2rdt+...)$$
$$=(1+rdt+...)(2+\sigma^2dt+...)-1-(1+2rdt+...)$$
$$=2+\sigma^2dt+2rdt-2-2rdt=\sigma^2 dt$$

after neglecting terms of order $dt^2$ and higher.